# Sql merge query

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I have these queries.

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT SUM(comment) FROM `tbl_1` t1 LEFT JOIN `tbl_2` t2 on  t1.id_id = t2.id WHERE create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)")->queryScalar();
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT SUM(comment) FROM `tbl_1` t1 LEFT JOIN `tbl_2` t2 on   t1.id_id = t2.id WHERE create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)")->queryScalar();
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT SUM(comment) FROM `tbl_1` t1 LEFT JOIN `tbl_2` t2 on t1.id_id = t2.id WHERE create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)")->queryScalar();
```

How can write this in one query?

Comment: What do you mean in one query? The conditions overlap each other. If you ask for interval greater than one week you also get interval greater than one day. Am I missing something ?

Comment: i have meny query with this format and when my db greater than normal size this query execute in long time.. i wanna resolve this problem

Answer (score 0):

As @geoandri said the conditions overlap so the only way to get that query in only one is using union of subqueries, but you don't obtain any performance doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking your question really is "How can I write one query that returns one row with these three columns?"

I have no way of testing this within MySql. If I had to do this within SQL, I'd use a command like this:

```
SELECT
    day_total = SUM(
        CASE
        WHEN create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        THEN comment
        ELSE 0
        END
    ),
    week_total = SUM(
        CASE
        WHEN create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK)
        THEN comment
        ELSE 0
        END
    ),
    month_total = SUM(comment)

FROM `tbl_1` t1
LEFT JOIN `tbl_2` t2 on  t1.id_id = t2.id
WHERE create_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

Note: anything that the `WHERE` clause selects, by default, falls into the one month category which is why I removed the `CASE WHEN ... END` from the `SUM()` of the `month_total` column.

Comment: Remember, I cannot test this.  My thought is yes you will because this is one command and not the three you currently have.

Comment: Another thought since you are passing the SELECT command, hard-code the dates rather than checking the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(...)`. 

Change `(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)` to the correct value for yesterday in MySQL. Then do the same for week & month. My thought pattern is it is faster to check `>=` with a hard-coded value than to get the date and subtract a value and then check `>=`.